# JavaScript Help, assign user input values to an array then to an UL

Tags: javascript

I am a student and this is a homework assignment for my JavaScript class, I have to make the following code work, it should take five places entered from the user and assign them to an array. Then display them in the list on the page. When I started it was not functional. It currently will only take 4 entries and displays only the first 3 on the list. It should take 5 entries and display 5 entries. I have tried to change the if statement that iterates the counter but it still only takes 4 places. I suspect something is out of order, or not numbered correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Hands-on Project 4-3</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
   <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <header>
      <h1>
         Hands-on Project 4-3
      </h1>
   </header>

   <article>
      <div id="results">
          <p id="resultsExpl"></p>
          <ul>
             <li id="item1"></li>
             <li id="item2"></li>
             <li id="item3"></li>
             <li id="item4"></li>
             <li id="item5"></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <form>
          <fieldset>
            <label for="placeBox" id="placeLabel">
              Type the name of a place, then click Submit:
            </label>
            <input type="text" id="placeBox" />
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <button type="button" id="button" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>
          </fieldset>
      </form>
   </article>
   <script>
      var places = []; // new array to store entered places
      var i = 1; // counter variable to track array indexes

      // function to add input to array and then generate list after 5th submission
      function processInput() {
         places[i] = document.getElementById("placeBox").value; // add entered value to array
         document.getElementById("placeBox").value = "" // clear text box
         if (i < 6) { // iterate counter variable
            ++i;
         }
         else { // add entered value to array and write results to document
            document.getElementById("resultsExpl").innerHTML = "You entered the following places:";
            var listItem = "";
            for (j = 1; j < 6; j++) { // write each array element to its corresponding list item
               listItem = "item" + j;
               document.getElementById(listItem).innerHTML = places[j];
            }

      }

      // add backward compatible event listener to Submit button
      var submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
      if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
        submitButton.addEventListener("click", processInput, false); 
      } else if (submitButton.attachEvent)  {
        submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", processInput);
      }
      }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. We will not simply solve your homework question for you. Tell us what you have tried so far, what is and isn't working, and any errors you are seeing.

Comment: @JCD I have updated the question, I did not ask you to do my homework, guidance in the direction of the issue or issues would be nice and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues I see. The biggest one which is probably tripping you up is the fact that `processInput()` is running *twice* every time you click the submit button.

First you assign an event handler inline the HTML itself:

`<button type="button" id="button" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>`

`onclick="processInput()"` assigns that click handler when it parses the HTML. So later on when you do this:

```
  // add backward compatible event listener to Submit button
  var submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
  if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", processInput, false); 
  } else if (submitButton.attachEvent)  {
    submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", processInput);
  }
  }
```

You're actually adding *another duplicate* event handler to the button's `onclick`, causing `processInput()` to run twice with every click. That causes the array to be filled with some unexpected values.

Another issue is the fact that the above block of code (adding the event listener in JavaScript) is *inside* of `processInput()` itself. So this is what happens:

1. HTML adds event listener to the onclick.
2. First time the button is clicked, `processInput()` runs once. `processInput()` adds a duplicate event listener to the onclick.
3. Subsequent button clicks fire `processInput()` twice; once from the HTML and once from the JavaScript.

In conclusion, pick one or the other. Either add the event listener inline in HTML or do it in JavaScript, not both. If you do it in JS, certainly make sure that the code that adds the event listener *isn't inside of the function it's adding*. Put it in the global context.

There are a couple of other small problems I see but you should be able to figure them out once you fix the event listener issues. A word of advice: when debugging your code it's helpful to add `console.log()` in certain places so that you can see the state of your variables and track down what is going wrong where.

Comment: Thank you so much for not only the help, but the explanation as well! I was able to get it to work after removing the inline HTML event listener, and just using the backwards compatibility. Have a great day!

Comment: Your information actually also helped me on another assignment I was having issues with, so thank you again!